# how to map header with dataframe when there is no data for the header in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is loaded from a file without headers. I defined header in my code and map it to the data in the dataframe. and then load this dataframe into a SQL table.
How ever, the data we receive not necessailry have all the columns always.

```
for example, 
header = ["filedate", "code", "errorID", "filename","errortype"]

df
20230821  1002   111   filename1   type1
20230821  1003   114   filename2   type1 
20230821  1002   444   filename2   type2 

df
20230821  111   filename1   type1
20230821  114   filename2   type1 
20230821  444   filename2   type2
```

Here, first column is date, second column is code, third column is errorID, fourth is filename and fifth column is errortype.

In second df, second column "code" is missing this has to be blank .

currently my code :

```
    final = {}
    for i,index in  zip(header ,df):
            final.update({i: df[index].tolist()})
    df_final= pd.DataFrame(final)
```

This code works fine if all columns are in my dataframe. but if my data frame is missing any of the columns but  in headers my code doesnt work.
I have to map all the columns defined in my header to my SQL table. If any column missing in  dataframe should be blank or null .Columns are always in order in the dataframe.

```
Final_df:
df_final
filedate  code   errorID   filename    errortype
20230821  1002   111       filename1   type1
20230821  1003   114       filename2   type1 
20230821  1002   444       filename2   type2 


df_final
filedate  code   errorID   filename    errortype
20230821         111       filename1   type1
20230821         114       filename2   type1 
20230821         444       filename2   type2
```

Comment: Is the missing column always "code"?

Comment: nope. it can be anything

Comment: Then how do you solve the ambiguity to determine which column(s) is/are missing?